# Cloning a repo and sourcing it to the RC file

Tags: linux

I am trying to install a extension to an addon (Forgit for FZF in Ubuntu to be specific).

However, on the install there is this line:

```
# manually
# Clone the repository and source it in your shell's rc file.
```

I am a noob when it comes to Linux terminal commands and the Linux eco-system in general. What does the above mean? If wanted to learn more about this where is a good place to start?

EDIT:
I am currently working inside Window's Terminal(WSL2) and using .bashrc as my RC file.
The specific repo in question is: github.com/wfxr/forgit

Thank you,

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and add a link to the software and the installation instructions. Maybe https://github.com/wfxr/forgit ? What shell do you use?

Comment: @Bodo Added! Bashrc and Windows Terminal

Comment: With "Window's Terminal" do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal? Are you using "Windows subsystem for Linux" (WSL)? I only use real Linux systems, so I cannot give any specific help here. Please specify this in your question or name the Linux distribution you use. As you mention `.bashrc` I assume your shell is Bash. Please add more specific questions what you need help with if my answer is not sufficient.

Comment: This seems to belong on the [Unix and Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Clone the repository" means to use `git` to get a copy of the repository. On GitHub use the green button labeled "Code". The command to clone the repository for https://github.com/wfxr/forgit is

```
git clone https://github.com/wfxr/forgit.git
```

You could also use the option "Download ZIP" to get a snapshot of the source code.

Assuming you run the `git` command in your HOME directory, you will get a directory `forgit` in your HOME directory. (*)

**Edit:** You can do this in any directory where you like as long as you have the necessary permissions. The `git clone ...` command will place the working directory below the current directory if you don't specify anything else. There is no specific place where you should place your Git repository / working directory.

"Source it" means to run the script in the same shell process that runs the calling script or command. Depending on your shell can you do this with

```
. /path/to/your/script/forgit.plugin.sh
```

or

```
. /path/to/your/script/forgit.plugin.zsh
```

I don't know `fish`, so I don't know what command this shell uses. There are other shells that may need

```
source /path/to/your/script/some-script
```

"Your shell's rc file" is a script file that is executed when a new shell process is started and is used to do your personal configuration of the shell. This might be `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or `.profile` depending on the shell you use. Some shells may use different files that are executed depending on the shell invocation (interactive shell, login shells, non-interactive shell, any shell ...).

Because you mentioned `.bashrc` in the question and assuming you cloned the Git repo as shown above (*) you can add

```
. $HOME/forgit/forgit.plugin.sh
```

to your `.bashrc`

**Edit:** If you used a different directory to clone or extract the source code, the command must match this directory.

In BASH or ZSH you can also use `source some-script` instead of `. some-script`. In contrast to `source`, `.` is Posix conformant. `source` and `.` do the same in BASH, in ZSH the search order is different, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68109/330217.

Comment: Is there a specific folder this git repo should be placed (besides the $HOME directory you mentioned)

Comment: @RizaKhan You can place it where you like. I edited the answer.